# Using checkbox to filter query Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm VERY new to working with Access, and SQL--thank you for your patience with me! I'm working on a query  based off of an inventory table:

tblInvnetory:
recordID (PK),
itemID,
setID,
other fields with info specific to item

Not all items have a setID.  I would like to have a checkbox on the form with the other search parameters to filter out records that include a setID (e.g. include items from sets). So if box is TRUE = return records with setID. If box is FALSE = return records with no setID.

Would an IIF statement accomplish this?  If so, any guidance on what the syntax would look like?

The other thought I've had is to include a checkbox in tblInventory that is "Item is part of Set".  So if in the table it is true, and the box on the form is true, it will only return records with a setID.  Would I also need an IIF statement for that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a job for *Xor*:

```sql
Where [Forms]![FormName]![CheckboxName] Xor Not (SetID Is Null)
```